# Make Jenkins pipeline appear as gitlab native pipeline in Gitlab ui

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a hook in gitlab integration. It trigers Jenkins pipeline job with unit tests. Job works just perfect, but it doesn't appear in gitlab pipelines and doesn't show tag merge request with label.

How can I pass Jenkins pipeline result to Gitlab and make it look like a native Gitlab pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're past this problem by now, but for anyone else reaching this page in search of a solution, then have a look at [gitlabCommitStatus](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/gitlab-plugin/#gitlabcommitstatus-update-the-commit-status-in-gitlab-depending-on-the-build-status).